# Require a path in one php file in Jumi to another php file in Jumi

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, jumi

I installed the Jumi extension to Joomla.

I uploaded the php files and one css file that I need to make an addition to the website.

I put pathnames to them for example:

```
components/com_jumi/order_confirm.php
components/com_jumi/review.php
components/com_jumi/includes/formValidations.php
components/com_jumi/includes/config.php
```

Now the file order_confirm.php has code to require the formValidation.php file:

```
require_once ("includes/formValidations.php");
```

But when I create a new menu item that points to the php file review.php it outputs the following warning and error:

```
Warning: require_once(includes/formValidations.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/37/9463737/html/components/com_jumi/views/application/view.html.php(40) : eval()'d code on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/formValidations.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/37/9463737/html/components/com_jumi/views/application/view.html.php(40) : eval()'d code on line 3
```

Does that mean the paths that I wrote for each file in Jumi is not the actual path for these files?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you,
Al

Comment: I guess this can be rephrased to ask what is the path I need for files uploaded by jumi as an application?

Comment: Did you set the 'Default Absolute Jumi Path' in plugin-manager / System / Jumi? - it is if you use the jumi extension like a plugin. In case you'are using like a module, then I think in module properties was the field for path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends how you are using jumi extensions.
1. In case you are using it as a plugin, then you have to set the option  'Default Absolute Jumi Path' in Plugin Manager / System - Jumi
2. In case you're using it like a module - in Module Manafer / jumi-module / advanced options / Default Absolute Jumi Path

Comment: I'll take a quick look at the properties and see if I need to set a path. I just downloaded it as an extension. So far I don't see any options for Jumi under plug-ins or extensions.

Comment: I see it now in the extensions but no options to work with really. I see it in Modules but it isn't enabled.

Comment: If you like to know where will be located your files, then you need to set it. Otherwise the Jumi will use it's default path. At all I'm always proceed by creating one folder in main directory, named 'jumi' and set mentioned above settings - and I have no problems.

Comment: If any way you are using it - it means you are using like a plugin - how are you caling the jumi files?

Comment: I echod the path and got the default path of jumi but it isn't working for the file I am requiring...I have no idea =[

Comment: I am adding a new menu item and it works if I comment out the require of the other file but I am just trying to now figure out how to make it work with the ability to require the other file that is uploaded through Jumi as well

Comment: Did you set your pat in: EXTENSIONS / Plug-In Manager / System-Jumi plugin?

Comment: I haven't, I don't see where that option is to be able to set your own path.

Comment: I found it! I am going to set it and see how this works... So I set it and then do the following? require_once ({jumi [formValidation.php]});

Comment: Yes that is what I found...but now what set any path? like: jumi/files/ ...?

Comment: I told you - make folder, store there your jumi files and yes on the end set there the path to this one folder.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to joomla I just researched it and is it creating a new folder in the media manager? and get that path?

Comment: Probably yes, but I'm working in other way - I'm always connected to the site via ftp client and do it directly. Probably via media manager will work too, but I simply not tried it.

Comment: But may be you'll need to do something else - As I understand you've pushed your php script by paste code in COMPONENTS/Jumi. If you worked in this way - the Jumi creates file, which is stored soewhere and may be will appear problems. To avoid this you'll need to store code in created folder in your php.file. After that from COMPONENTS remove pasted code and point to your file - look in my sample shot : http://prntscr.com/6vikqk